# CoordinatorLayout split in two equal parts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I would like to split my layout in two equal parts one with an Imageview and the other with a Recyclerview, both wrapped in a CoordinatorLayout. 
For some reason this is not working, scrolling the recycler view does not scroll the image, any ideas ?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mPreview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/preview_iv"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/mGalleryRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: AppBarLayout is supposed to be a direct child of a CoordinatorLayout. It does not work otherwise. What effect are your trying to achieve? A collapsing toolbar with an image and then a list of items below?

Comment: i think you are talking about.. `Collapsible toolbar with recycler view `.

Comment: I would like that when I scroll up the imageview follows the scroll and when  scrolling down the imageview comes down, similar to "enterAlways" effect

Comment: Like Instagram gallery picker